# ellipsis not working in select menu options

Tags: select, ellipsis

I have tried ellipsis in paragraph and div it works fine but not working in select menu options, I want fixed width in option of  menu. Well i have tried something here but not getting the result.

http://jsfiddle.net/t5eUe/48/

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289769/ellipsis-for-overflow-text-in-dropdown-boxes

Comment: ya it works fine when u take uniform.js