# Unable to limit <option> width

Tags: css, width, html-select, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a select box populated by some database fields. Some fields are way too long, so the `option` width doesn't end. I would like to limit the width, and display an ellipsis using the `text-overflow` property. However it does not work.

This is how I am trying to do it :

```
select option {
    display: block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

Any idea how I could achieve this without JS?

Many thanks

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289769/ellipsis-for-overflow-text-in-dropdown-boxes

Comment: Thanks for this indication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar question at this link. In Chrome and safari it may not be possible to show the ellipsis and you may have to put up with -webkit-appearance: none.

[Ellipsis for overflow text in dropdown boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289769/ellipsis-for-overflow-text-in-dropdown-boxes)