# text-overflow:ellipsis doesn't work in HTML select properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, drop-down-menu

Though text-overflow: ellipsis in css works properly in div, spans and etc it does not work properly in HTML select. Only the text overflow will be hidden from the select. But not ends with dots as the default behavior of text-overflow

Can anyone suggest any workarounds for this  please ?

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/t5eUe/)`enter code here`

Comment: This isn't supported behavior, besides you should be styling the `option`. You might be able to get around this by using something like jQuery's [Select2](https://select2.github.io/).

Comment: @SmrMano, Check the answer given by "Steven Web" in the below link, [set dropdown list option with ellipses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625942/set-dropdown-list-option-with-ellipses) [Working DEMO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625942/set-dropdown-list-option-with-ellipses) HTH

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ellipsis for overflow text in dropdown boxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289769/ellipsis-for-overflow-text-in-dropdown-boxes)

Answer (score -2):

Add

```
select, select option {
```

instead of

```
select
```

in your css

You had given style to only the select tag header and not the option tag