# Replace <option /> text when selected

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a dynamically created set of `option`s, some of which may have a length of over 15 symbols.

The `select` component has a custom button to reset it, which normally looks like
[image: Option with normal length]

When the `option` value is more that 15 symbols though, it looks awful
[image: Option with length > 15]

I was looking for a solution to change the value, but only if the option is selected.

The one I came up with makes the selected value look okay, but it also changes the way value is display in select window:

```
{title.length > 15 ? `${title.slice(0, 14)}...` : title}
```

It looks nice:
[image: Option looks nice]

**But it changes the way it is displayed in the select window**:
[image: Bug]

So I was wondering if there is a solution to set another value to option **only** when it is selected, i.e. to not affect its value in the select window.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/zlm3mlo7pm?fontsize=14

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: You might want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24964722/9150652)

Answer (score 1):

CSS for the win!

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

set the width of the text (I assume `p` tag) to be within the `X` and you should be good to go

```
function TextWithEllipsis(props) {
    const styles = {
        width: '50px';
        textOverflow: ellipsis;
    };
    return (<p style={styles} >{props.text}</p>)
}
```