# How to add ellipsis on a select element when the text is too long using html5

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to show the text ending with ellipsis when a string is too long on a HTML select element.

I've created a simple example:

```
<select>
    <option>Just a long long long text?</option>
</select>
```

and the css:

```
select {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;    
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Bonomi/z9mqesj3/6/)

As you can see the overflow hidden is working but not the ellipsis.
Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ellipsis for overflow text in dropdown boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289769/ellipsis-for-overflow-text-in-dropdown-boxes)

Comment: Yes, I used the hack suggestion, with JavaScript